# how to add data arrays in datatables in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

I want to create datatables, with the data that I got from the query builder, and I want to add that data to an array that I process myself, I try with this code

```
 return Datatables::of($users)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('number_rek', $array)
                ->make(true);
```

but the data is like this

```
balance: "405.868"
no_register: ["4211070802", "5212370803", "-", "-", "-"]
0: "4211070802"
1: "5212370803"
2: "-"
3: "-"
4: "-"
DT_RowIndex: 1
```

my expectation is that each row of datatables has one no_register like this

```
balance: "405.868"
no_register: "4211070802"
DT_RowIndex: 1

balance: "502.500"
no_register: "5212370803"
DT_RowIndex: 2
```

i use library from yajrabox

Comment: Add a mutator in your User model to only return one row

Comment: do you have refrences?

Comment: Make it manually using model::all and table tag and add id for table after that add function datatable in script tag